# Update VSTO Excel 2010 add-in installation

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsto, windows-installer

I am currently working on a Excel 2010 add-in and I've managed to create a Windows Installer project for it which is installing the add-in successfully on any machine. However, I am facing an issue: in order to install a new version of the add-in I have to first uninstall the previous one... 
In the Windows Installer project I've set the RemovePreviousVersions property to True, but this didn't help in any way... 
In order to create the MSI I've used this guide which doesn't mention anything about updates... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff937654.aspx

Any ideas and suggestions would be appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: The Visual Studio 2010 installer projects are ugly and therefore Microsoft has removed them from Visual Studio 2012 in favor of WiX setup projects. I would recommend authoring your setup in WiX or some other installation tool and follow their tutorials. I would also recommend against using batch files and other hacks to get your installer to work, as they aren't very robust and are much more likely to fail.

Answer (score 0):

You probably get the message "Another version of this product is already installed"?

Usually, this message is showed if you created a package, installed it, modified its contents and then you tried to install it again without uninstalling the original one. Basically, Windows Installer can upgrade the original package only if the modified one has a higher version and a different Product Code. If you don't want to create a new version of the package, you need to uninstall the original MSI before installing the modified one.

A simple method would be to create a small batch file in which you call msiexec with the /x option to remove the old version, than you call it with /i option to install the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Every MSI package has UpgradeCode. With help of it you can manage upgrades.
In your case, if you have previous MSI, need take this code and add it to UpgradeTable of your new MSI. More information on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372379%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)